# Help! I walk through every door I try to open!

Tags: xcom-ufo-defense

I'm playing a new game of x-com: Enemy Unknown, and the first mission my x-com soldiers were able to perform was capturing a landed UFO.

Due to a combination of random chance and luck (bad or good? I can't say...) I have secured the entirety of the exterior space with nary a Sectoid or Floater to be found. I have my soldiers massing in front of the landed UFO, but so far the aliens want to do this, "the Hard Way".

Obviously, charging straight through and triggering all kinds of reaction fire from however many completely healthy aliens remain aboard is a Bad Idea. But in the various farm doors, etc. that my x-com agents have used so far, they seem dead set on only opening the door when they want to pass through it.

How can I open the door to see what's in the room while not also simultaneously moving through the doorway? I could have sworn I was able to do it previously, but I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to do so again.

Comment: As a side note: If the UFO was shot down, sometimes the power source has exploded on impact, leaving a handy hole in the roof. Sniping through this hole from the top of a nearby building or throwing in grenades is a handy (if unsportsmanlike) trick.

Comment: "I say we take off and nuke the site from orbit. Its the only way to be sure."

Comment: "Me and my squad of ultimate badasses will protect you! Check it out! Independently targeting particle beam phalanx. Vwap! Fry half a city with this puppy. We got tactical smart missiles, phase-plasma pulse rifles, RPGs, we got sonic electronic ball breakers! We got nukes, we got knives, sharp sticks... "

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In UFO: Enemy Unknown (also known as X-Com) there was no way to open a door without passing through it to the next tile. If I remember correctly, they implemented right-click to open the door in Terror From The Deep.

Comment: Yup.  On the version of TFTD that I played, CTRL+click also worked to open dooors, and I think also tapping the directional arrows.

Comment: What I usually do in such cases is save and load quite a bit. Or, as a less cheap alternative, use enough explosives to try and punch a hole in one of the UFO walls (though I doubt you brought along enough firepower to do that).

Comment: This is X-COM.  March your newest member through the door.  Then follow it up with every grenade and explosive charge you have, set to a timer of 3 just to give the guy a chance to get out if he should somehow survive the barrage.  Fighting aliens aint pretty.

Comment: In some farmhouses, you can "peek" through the windows first.

Comment: Mind controlled aliens love to volunteer for this job! Of course, by that point you can probably just blow a hole in the roof and pour in grenades.

Comment: [OpenXCom](http://openxcom.org/) added the [right click to open door](http://ufopaedia.org/index.php/Differences_to_X-COM_(OpenXcom)) feature.

Answer (score 9):

Even though you can't prevent entering a door in UFO:EU, there are ways to mitigate retaliatory fire.

- Use a motion scanner while outside the door, it lets you see if there are anything inside.
- Put some proximity grenades outside and wait a few turns, see if any comes out.
- Use a HWP to open the door (if its two wide), they are more expendable than well trained troopers.
- Use the blaster launcher to blow up a hole somewhere else or look for an alternate entrance.

Comment: I'll add a few tricks: pop a smoke grenade before opening the door, the extra cover might save you; if there's a hole in the roof, toss in a grenade or three; use new recruits to open the door, not experienced soldiers; make sure there's nobody standing immediately behind the sucker--umm... hero who opens the door else they might get blasted, too; place units with good reaction to the right and left of the door.  Also make sure to place the proximity grenade one space away from the door due to a bug.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, there isn't any way to just open a door without charging through. Grenades were always heavily underused, they are very powerful in the early stages of the game when your troops did not have great weaponry. If the UFO was shot down then there may well be holes in the body that will accept the gift of a grenade.

Failing that you'll just have to run someone in to soak up that reaction fire and then follow up with your main soldiers.

Answer (score 0):

Move the mouse cursor over the unit that is next to the door (alien or human, doesn't matter) and press 'v' on the keyboard. That will open the door or deactivate the forcefield.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the 1994 game X-COM: UFO Defence and not the 2012 reboot XCOM: Enemy Unknown? The question here is about the former, much older game.